# Apache Kafka Consumer Deserialization Error

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am using kafka for consuming messages. While consuming messages, there are possibility that I may get different messages which would cause DeserializationException. I want to skip the records that causes DeserializationException and process the one which is not causing any issues.

All Kafka related properties are configured through properties like below,

```
kafka:
    producer:
      bootstrap-servers:
        - PRODUCER_BROKERS
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
    consumer:
      key-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
      bootstrap-servers:
        - CONSUMER_BROKERS
      properties:
        key.deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
        value.deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
        spring.deserializer.key.delegate.class: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
        spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
```

When I googled I get some solution by implementing `ErrorHandler` from [How to catch deserialization error in Kafka-Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55923893/how-to-catch-deserialization-error-in-kafka-spring) but since I am using properties I am not sure, how can I bind it to `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory`. What is a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration looks correct.

The default error handler (`DefaultErrorHandler`) will discard (log) the records with failed deserialization errors.